# Cannot "Enter Time Machine" from Mountain Lion

Tags: time-machine, macos

Upgraded to Mountain Lion yesterday. Time Machine backups continue to run without any reported errors. (Backups are to a HD shared by a Lion Server on the network).

Problem is When I choose `Enter Time Machine` (or double-click on the Time Machine application icon) nothing happens. No window. No error. No...nothing. I do notice that the remote HD mounts in the Finder... but that's it.

I've reviewed a [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27507/time-machine-enter-time-machine-menu-command-does-not-do-anything) which appears to be Lion (or perhaps Snow Leopard) related. But this is not acceptable as I don't want to erase my whole backup and start anew...as I can't afford to toss my only Lion backup.

Anyone know what's up? And how to get my TM working properly under MLion?

Comment: Open /Applications/Utilities/Console.app and see if there are any relevant messages there.

Comment: Nothing. not a peep in the logs related to TM

Comment: hm.. same thing. didn't notice until read your question

Comment: Is this error still troubling you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reformat the external drive I use for Time Machine. It said there was a permissions problem, that it was Read Only - which it wasn't, and a look at the Info for it confirmed it was Read & Write. Still, I just erased the drive and started again. Works fine now.

Comment: I'd rather not have to erase the entire backup if at all possible...

Comment: I ended up buying another drive, effectively reformatting, and starting anew.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to Time Machine preferences and removing that drive from the list of backup drives? Try that, then re-add it. If that doesn't work, subtract it again, look at it in Disk Utility, perhaps rename it to something else, verify and repair the volume, eject then remount it, add to Time Machine backup list, attempt to enter TM again. If no luck, subtract, rename to the original name, re-add to backup list.

Answer (score -2):

While in opened time machine, press Shift-Command-C it will make TM clickable.  Apple is too busy to change sizes of iPhones, iPads to call it a new version and they forget of about their softwares.