# Cannot enter Time Machine

Tags: time-machine

I have been running Time Machine for about 10 months with no problems. Now when I try to enter time machine, nothing happens. Just like in other posts I have read. I run Lion with no apparent problems and the backups work fine as I can see them in Finder and access the files there. The problem is that clicking to enter Time Machine does nothing, with no error or anything.

Any ideas? My backup is to a USB-connected dedicated 1 TB hard drive.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27507/time-machine-enter-time-machine-menu-command-does-not-do-anything

Comment: Would you review the linked question above and edit your question to indicate how the answer proposed there doesn't help your situation? As it stands, your question reads as a perfect duplicate of the other one.

Answer (score -1):

While in TM press Shift-Command-C.

Comment: Can you please add more details? Specifically, what you think OP is experiencing and why Shift-Command-C would help?